# How to download files from Dropbox using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, download, retrofit2, dropbox-api

I'm trying to download audio and video files from the Dropbox API into my Android app using the Retrofit 2 library but I'm getting a JSON error because I'm not mapping the response correctly, but since the response is apparently the actual file I'm not sure how I can handle it.

Here is my code:

**Media class**

```
data class Media(
    @Expose val id: String,
    @Expose @SerializedName("name") val title: String,
    var position: Int,
    var uri: String
)
```

**API interface**

```
@POST("2/files/download")
fun download(@Header("Dropbox-API-Arg") pathJson: MediaRequest): Call<Media>
```

I added an interceptor to my client that adds the authorisation header to all calls and it's working because calls to other endpoints are receiving their responses properly.

**MediaRequest class**

```
data class MediaRequest(val path: String)
```

This class, when sent on the request, is serialised to JSON just as expected by the Dropbox API documentation, like the example below:

```
{ "path": "id:abcd1234" }
```

**API call**

```
val request = MediaRequest(media.id)
downloadApi.download(request).enqueue(object : Callback<Media> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Media>, response: Response<Media>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            // handle response
        } else {
            onError()
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Media>, t: Throwable) {
        onError(t)
    }
})
```

I also checked the exact same call with Postman and there are no problems with the call itself because I'm getting the response, but from what I saw in the Postman response, I should expect to receive the file itself as a response because when I tried downloading an MP3 audio file the response was an encoded string beginning with ID3, which means it's an MP3 file, as the screenshot below shows:

[image: Dropbox API download endpoint response on Postman]

I already know that mapping the response with that `Media` class I created is not the right approach but I don't know how I can handle that response correctly in order to have the downloaded file, so any help will be much appreciated.

PS: I don't want to use the Dropbox SDK because I feel it would be quite an overkill since that's the only reason I'm calling their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved my problem was by mapping the response as a `ResponseBody` object and then calling `response.body().byteStream()` to get the contents as a byte stream and then decode them into a proper file.

Source: https://gldraphael.com/blog/downloading-a-file-using-retrofit/